# How can I center the scrollToColumn in React Virtualized's Grid?

Tags: react-virtualized

`scrollToColumn` will guarantee that the Grid's column will be visible. How can it be rendered so that it's centered in the grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the `scrollToAlignment` property:

> Controls the alignment scrolled-to-rows. The default ("auto") scrolls
>   the least amount possible to ensure that the specified row is fully
>   visible. Use "start" to always align rows to the top of the list and
>   "end" to align them bottom. Use "center" to align them in the middle
>   of container.

Assuming you're using version 7.1.2+ this property will be supported.